# PostgreSQL fill out nulls with previous value by category

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying fill out some nulls where I just need them to be the previous available value for a name (sorted by date).

So, from this table:

[image]

I need the query to output this:

[image]

Now, the idea is that for Jane, on the second and third there was no score, so it should be equal to the previous date on which an score was available, for Jane. And the same for Jon. I am trying coalesce and range, but range is not implemented yet in Redshift. I also looked into other questions and they don't fully apply to different categories. Any alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186218/carry-over-long-sequence-of-missing-values-with-postgres

Comment: Postgres or Redshift?

Comment: Redshift - Postgres

Comment: Despite what the Amazon marketing is telling you: Redshift is not Postgres. Are you using both?

Comment: No, only Redshift. Postgres syntax usually applies

Answer (score 2):

```
select day, name, 
coalesce(score, (select score 
                 from [your table] as t 
                 where t.name = [your table].name and t.date < [your table].date 
                 order by date desc limit 1)) as score
from [your table]
```

The query straightforwardly implements the logic you described:

1. if score is not null, `coalesce` will return its value without executing the subquery
2. if score is null, the subquery will return the last available score for that name before the given date

Answer (score 1):

It's a "gaps and islands" problem and a query can be like this

```
SELECT
    day,
    name,
    MAX(score) OVER (PARTITION BY name, group_id) AS score
FROM (    
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN score IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY day) AS group_id
    FROM data
) groups
ORDER BY name DESC, day
```

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=af1208ea8ef00b30b8fc9b93c7998892)

Comment: There is a problem with this query: "prev" will contain all previous not null scores for a given name, not just the last one. You'll end up getting multiple rows for the same date and name in that case (i.e. if Jon has a score of 5 on 2022/01/01, 7 on 2022/01/02 and null on 2022/01/03, you'll get 2 rows for 2022/01/03, one with a score of 5 and one with 7)

Comment: see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=69277882a2b0b0a7e01880e7c11125f0 where I edited Jane's scores to show the case I'm describing

Comment: @cogitoergosum Thank you. I missed it. Updated my answer and fiddle. Meanwhile your query returns `NULL` for `score` for row `2022-01-03, Jane, NULL`. Have a nice day